# Link to New Document in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

in SharePoint Online, how to add a button/link to create new document based on a content type template?

[image: o]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to enable the Content Type for that particular document library.

[Enable content type for list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-support-for-multiple-content-types-in-a-list-or-library-80506b54-361d-4847-bce3-67e30f497256)

Once, the content type is enabled, add your content type to that library.

[Add a content type to list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60)

After performing the above step, you will see the option under the new button to create the document using your content type template.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use modern experience instead of classic experience. In modern experience, you could add a template more easily, just click add-> new template.

[image]